# How to start learning the Chipmunk physics engine with the cocos2D?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Please suggest me how to start the Learning of the Chipmunk Physics with the cocos2D engine with the game suggestion.

Thanks for the suggestion in advance!

Comment: On StackOverflow we like specific questions that can be answered definitively. For your question you can find good answers easily just by querying google: http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=chipmunk+tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good tutorial on chipmunk http://www.alexandre-gomes.com/articles/chipmunk/